# Making an object move in javascript using up, down, left and right keys

Tags: javascript

EDIT: this code is now working but only in js fiddle and not when i view it in the browser from dreamweaver.

Is there any reason for this?

I am trying to make a basic snake game in javascript and HTML5.

Everything was working great until I tried to make my rectangle move using the 37,38,39,40 keys.

It moves across the screen but I just cannot control it no matter what I do.

I have tried other methods or writing this code and nothing works.

I have tried using other keys such as letters too.

Any help in plain clear English would be great.

I would love to know what I am doing wrong as everything is working fine apart from the keymoves. I would rather not use JS fiddle or Jquery for any of this if possible.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var xcoord = 100;
  var ycord = 100;
  window.addEventListener('keydown', whatKey, true);
}
function whatKey(evt) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillText(evt.keyCode, 50, 50);
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 39:
      xcoord = xcoord + 10;
      if (xcoord > 750) {
        xcoord = 750;
      }
      if (xcoord > 150 && xcoord < 250 && ycoord > 150 && ycoord < 250) {
        snd.play();
        xcoord = xcoord - 10;
      }
      break;
    case 37:
      xcoord = xcoord - 10;
      if (xcoord < 0) {
        xcoord = 0;
      }
      if (xcoord > 150 && xcoord < 250 && ycoord > 150 && ycoord < 250) {
        snd.play();
        xcoord = xcoord + 10;
      }
      break;
    case 40:
      ycoord = ycoord + 10;
      if (ycoord > 350) {
        ycoord = 350;
      }
      if (xcoord > 150 && xcoord < 250 && ycoord > 150 && ycoord < 250) {
        snd.play();
        ycoord = ycoord - 10;
      }
      break;
    case 38:
      ycoord = ycoord - 10;
      if (ycoord < 0) {
        ycoord = 0;
      }
      if (xcoord > 150 && xcoord < 250 && ycoord > 150 && ycoord < 250) {
        snd.play();
        ycoord = ycoord + 10;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `snd`? Why do you define `xcoord` and `ycoord` in the load event handler if you want to use then in `whatKey`? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Bernard... please make sure to select the appropriate answer.  Also did you solve the jsFiddle vs your IDE issue?  That would be something for another issue here on SO

Comment: hey sorry for delay in voting answer - had to finish a project! all done, thanks for your help. I had made a small error maybe in the html file which was preventing it from working in a browser but all sorted

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted out w. your IDE.  Since you are looking to make a game, once you get to a point where you might consider incorporating a game framework, check out the javaScript port of Ash.  It's an entity framework and may be overkill for your snake game, but would probably be suitable for anything more complicated - http://www.ashframework.org/

Comment: I will most definitely look into that. I have literally just started learning javascript so would be interested in anything that may help when working on more complicated projects. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Leo said is probably one if not **the** culprit, but needs some more explanation.  Your have defined local variables on the `window.onload` method.  Once that method executes and is over, the variable `context` and the others you've defined there are gone.  Then when `whatKey` executes, you are getting `undefined` and probably some javascript console errors.

So a quick fix is to define these variables outside of the scope of the `window.onload` method like so:

```
(function(){

   var canvas;
   var context;
   var xcoord;
   var ycord;

   function whatKey() { ... }

   window.onload = function() {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', whatKey, true);
   }
})();
```

Comment: Great thanks! I have got it working in JS fiddle but not when I view it in browser from dreamweaver. I have done this before I saw your answer. Should I add this and replace the addeventlistener that I already have? So I am just defining the functions?

Comment: I assume what is working in JS Fiddle and what is in your IDE (Dreamweaver) are the same aside from some of the JS Fiddle magic that happens outside of your control?

Can you share your JS Fiddle?  Might help to see what specifically you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not sure what your experience level is in development so please pardon me if some of this is terribly obvious but I figure it's worth covering.   did you check to make sure your javascript is being pulled into the browser? via a script tag or is this embedded? tried using a self-executing function like in my answer above? I have no experience w. DW so I am just throwing things to see what might stick.  Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

`context` is a local variable within the onload handler. In keydown handler `whatKey` you don't have a variable `context`.